# How to organize data and batches for many sets of time series data for a recurrent neural network?

Tags: regression, time-series, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis

For example, I have data from 2010-01-01 to 2020-01-01, but many sets of similar data that I want to train from with the same features. I want clarified, if every dataset have the same length (say 10 years), then for batch size, is it possible to just divide the number of rows by the number of datasets? This way, the number of batches is just the number of datasets I have, and each batch will be different data, basically starting from the beginning of the a time-series. Is this a good format to feed into a recurrent neural network? I'm trying to predict a feature a certain number of days away from the last input the model gets

date

2010-01-01 (start of batch 1?)

2010-01-02

.
.
.

2020-01-01

(different set of time-series data)

2010-01-01 (start of batch 2?)

2010-01-02

.
.
.

2020-01-01